# DIV on the right side ... what's a good solution?

Tags: css

I want to have a few divs one below the next one.
Some divs I want to align them right. 
If I use float:right I fail because the next divs are pretty much aligned with them.

so to achieve this:

```
<div>...[left]...</div>
<div>...[right]...</div>
<div>...[left]...</div>
```

I have ended up with using a table:

```
<div>...[left]...</div>
<table width='100%'>
<tr>
<td align=right>...[right]...</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>...[left]...</div>
```

Surely I could do better than this. 
But how ?
Can somebody help ?

p.s.
note [left] and [right] denote some other html elements - not just simple text for which text-align would do the trick

Comment: Can you [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) your problem?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. You want them one above the other but you want their contents aligned right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [clear](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control) property: check out [this jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vq7Zn/).